# Python: programe takes large computer memory

Tags: python, list

I am new to python. Here I want to calculate the 2nd and 4th order central moment ('stats.mstats.moment') of a random variable '_b' in 10 bins. So I stored data in a 2D list first. But if the number of events/iteration is very large then it takes a large amount of computer memory. Is there any way so that it takes smaller computer memory and time? Can anyone please help?

Here is my code?

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

max_event = 100000000
a_bin = 10  # number each bin from 0-->10 where cumulant calculation will be done

# Define 2D array for [ bin, here 0->10][proton in each bin]
pArray = [[] for nn in range(a_bin)]
neve = [0 for i in range(a_bin)]

for ii in range(0, max_event):

    _a = np.random.randint(10)
    _b = np.random.randint(120)

    if ii % 100000 == 0:
        print(ii, _a, _b)

    for j in range(0, a_bin):
        if _a == j:
            pArray[j].append(_b)
            neve[j] += 1

print("filling done!")

for k in range(0, a_bin):

    mu2 = stats.mstats.moment(pArray[k], moment=2)
    mu4 = stats.mstats.moment(pArray[k], moment=4)

    print('serial = %d, mu_2 = %f , mu_4 = %f, event = %d' %
          (k, mu2, mu4, neve[k]))
    # print k, neve[k], c1[k], c2[k], c3[k], c4[k], c5[k], c6[k]

print("calculation done!")
```

Comment: If you're using Python 2, `range` will create a list of integers. Use `xrange`, or, better yet, Python 3.

Comment: 100 million integers would take about 0.4 GB.

Comment: Have you considered using Google colab?